# JPA Query para hacer un login

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, login

Buenas noches compañeros de stackOverflow tengo un problema a la hora de crear el siguiente método que valida un login.

```
public Usuarios loginExist(String username, String password) {
    try {
        EntityManager em;
        EntityTransaction t;
        em = ConnectionFactory.getEntityManager();
        t = em.getTransaction();

        t.begin();
        TypedQuery<Usuarios> query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Usuarios u WHERE"
                + " u.usuario = :usuario AND u.contrase\u00f1a = :contrase\u00f1a", Usuarios.class);
        query.setParameter("usuario", username);
        query.setParameter("contrase\u00f1a", password);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

El problema es cuando invoco ese método con valores reales de la base de datos (en OracleDB) es que sólo me retorna el usuario la primera vez y despúes aunque los valores sean correctos arroja null.
Por ejemplo si hago un ciclo con más de una iteración y dentro invoco el método con los mismos datos sólo la primera vez arroja el usuario despues sólo null.
Espero su respuesta, gracias.

Comment: Estás omitiendo el detalle de la excepción. Lo mínimo e indispensable que haces con una excepción en Java es loguear la excepción, ya sea con `e.printStackTrace()` o `e.printStackTrace(System.out)`. Cuando hagas el cambio y ejecutes el código, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el texto del stacktrace, con esa información podremos ayudarte.

Comment: En el catch agregué `e.printStackTrace(System.out);` antes de `return null` y al probarlo arrojaba el error que no se había cerrado la transacción entonces sólo era cuestión de hacer un commit(); antes de devolver un usuario. Gracias